# How to change padding on this navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to change the padding so when the screen becomes too small, the links don't go onto 2 lines but instead the horizontal scroll comes up. Is it possible to do this using just CSS? I don't want to use javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.top_menu {
    position:fixed; 
    background: #F5F5F5;
    width:100%; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    height:20px;       /* decide on this at some stage */
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background: transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:75px; 
    left:0; 
    height:25px;       /* decide on this at some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this at some stage */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  /* decide on this at some stage */
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;  /* decide on this at some stage */
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:2px;  /* decide on this at some stage */
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this at some stage */
    color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this at some stage */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top_menu"></div>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="ty-menu__items">
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#home">new in</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#news">homeware</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#contact">decorating</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">diy</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">furniture</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">bathroom</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">garden</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">offers</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check how to use media querys

Comment: ^Agreed @some width `overflow-x: scroll;` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A media query does the trick. Try adding this to the bottom of your CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .ty-menu__items {
        width: 800px;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6wrjnbj7/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get only the x-overflow to produce a scroll? I tried but it didn't produce a scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/6wrjnbj7/1/

Comment: It's `overflow-x`, not `x-overflow`. And you'll want to keep the height more than 25px. http://jsfiddle.net/6wrjnbj7/2/

Comment: What if I want the scroll to appear at the bottom of the page as it does on this site? Do I then need to create a div to wrap around everything on the page?

Comment: Well, sure. Or you could just set the body `min-width` to `800px`. http://jsfiddle.net/djkj7yvx/

Comment: Where would I add that to this though? jsfiddle.net/6wrjnbj7/2

Comment: All the fixed positioning makes it a little bit trickier. Without seeing the rest of the site/code, I'm solving it by removing the media query, adding a footer element that is not fixed, and applying min-width to the footer and the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/wqux0kmj/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property to `scroll` in CSS,  which should work give you have fixed height to 20px.

As Medda86 said media queries within the CSS will allow you to make responsive css at certain breakpoints (widths), see the [google guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) for this.